# Z-Index with Sub-Menu

Tags: css, z-index

I'm actually developping a website for a customer and I have 1 big  problem.

Site in development: http://fuc.inexo.ca
I have a menu on the left, that have a  low z-index because the layout have to come on top of this menu.

Now, my  problem is that I want to sub-menu to be on top of the layout and the menu.
I  try almost everything with z-index but never figure out.
The site is on  Joomla 2.5 and the menu is ARI Ext Menu.

The menu on the left is working fine now. I want to leave it like this, at the same position, underneat the layout. (To give a round effect). The problem is with the sub-menu (the second level of menu). For example, if you put your mouse ''Realisations'' on the menu of the left, you will see the submenu but he is under the layout. I want it on top of it. Only for the submenu.

Any help will be really  appreciated!

Thank you so much!

Nicolas

Comment: do not use personal websites(http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). use jsfiddle.net, screen shots, css examples, etc instead

Answer (score 0):

You would simply need to set the sub-menu with a higher z-index than the other elements.  If you're not sure just set it to a really high number, like 1000.  You can find where the submenu's styling is being applied through FireBug, and then give it:

```
z-index: 1000;
```

I also agree with @carrie as well about not using personal websites, and using jsfiddle.net instead.

Comment: Did you test this?  I tried the same and for some reason it would not work for me.